# Scala ArrayBuffer append always at end or not?

Tags: scala

With the following code repeated many times:

```
var name = ArrayBuffer[String]() 
name += "GeeksForGeeks"
...
name -= "GeeksForGeeks"
...
name += "xyz"
```

Can I always guarantee that an entry is added at the end even if the max size of ArrayBuffer is reached and a new array allocated, even if there are are empty slots in ArrayBuffer due to deletion of element(s)? Or is the array compacted upon a deletion of an entry always? I cannot see from examples done.

Not 100% clear from docs. I want to be really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` is an alias for `addOne`, and despite not being clearly documented as such `addOne` is also the implementation of `append` for all `Buffer`s. So in other words `+=` and `append` are the same thing for an `ArrayBuffer`. And `append` by definition always adds elements at the end.

The exception is if you were to mutate an `ArrayBuffer` concurrently from multiple threads. Then you will probably corrupt the internal data structures.

Comment: OK, I am simulating some stuff with one writer and one reader whereby the array simulates a database write from KAFKA. In practice there would only be a single thread processing. Thanks.